# how to achieve Marathi or Hindi text in textbox while typing through keyboard

Tags: javascript, html

How to achieve Marathi or Hindi text in a textbox while typing through keyboard?

Like [this site](http://www.manogat.com/) in right hand side text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check their source? The page has following script:

```
textFieldArr[textFieldArr.length]="edit-search-block-form-1";
devExists = true;
var cs1=''; 
var cs2=''; 
var cs3='';
var acModeSet = true;
function setAcMode(el)
{
  acModeSet=el.checked;
}
function tfWordComplete()
{
  if (acModeSet) 
  {
//if (dx) alert ( '1 s1= ' +s1+ ' s2= ' +s2+ ' s3= ' +s3 );
cs1 = s1; cs2=s2; cs3=s3;
    checkTfAutoCorrect();
  }
  else
  {
      var tt = 0;
    for ( tt in textFieldArr )
    {
        cb = document.getElementById('ac_'+textFieldArr[tt])
        if (cb!= undefined) cb.checked=true;
    }
    acModeSet = true;
  }
}
```

Which is activated because of its `onclick` even in `input` field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Transliterate](http://www.google.com/transliterate) to achieve a similar behavior . Look at the [API](http://code.google.com/apis/language/#Transliteration) for more information